# Angular 2- Enable Multiple Components with view on one path state?

Tags: angular, typescript

> How to enable multiple components with one path state in Angular 2?
>   Just like ui-router, route Provider with one state to open multiple views in angularJs!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `router-outlet` to render multiple components in a certain route path.

Example code [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Su2fNPKOnQkZpnUb99Vh?p=preview)

Comment: @HAri could you be more specific? What do you see that indicate that the outlet is not working properly?

Comment: i found this error "cannot match any routes: ' PageA' "
{
        path: 'PageA',
        children: [
            {path: '', component:PageAComponent},
            {path: '', component: FormAComponent,outlet:'formA'},
            {path: '', component: FormBComponent,outlet:'formB'},
        ]
}
<a [routerLink]="['/PageA']">Page One Link</a>